# Need Help with Studying Binary Search Tree Pseudo-code

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search

I’m studying for a midterm. Can anyone help me get started with this question from my textbook?

Write a function to print out all items of a binary search tree with value v such that  min_val ≤ v ≤ max_val.

You can start from the following prototype:
template 
void
BSTree::PrintRange( const Comparable & min_val,
const Comparable & max_val ) const;

Analyze the running time of your function in terms of the number of nodes n and the
number of elements k in the range using O (Big-Oh) notation.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple double recursion.

```
BSTree::PrintRange( const Comparable & min_val, const Comparable & max_val ) const
{
  if(min_val<=v && v<=max_value)
  {
     print(v);
     if(left!=NULL)
        left.PrintRange(min_val,max_val);
     if(right!=NULL)   
        right.PrintRange(min_val,max_val);
  }
  else if(v<min_val) //go to the right to find a bigger value 
  {
     if(right!=NULL)
       right.PrintRange(min_val,max_val);
  }
  else //v>max_val
  { //go to the left to find a smaller value
     if(left != NULL)
       left.PrintRange(min_val,max_val);
  }

}
```

Comment: The run time is actually O(logN) where N is the number of nodes in the tree.